# Drag and drop functionality not working in selenium chromedriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on a drag and drop functionality using selenium chromedriver. But unfortunately unable to achieve it. I am using following piece of code,

```
public void dragAndDropElement() {
    try {
        WebElement imgToDrag = driver.findElement(By
                .className("imageclassname"));
        WebElement dropHere = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("panelcssname"));

        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        Actions actions = null, movetoElement = null;

        actions = action.clickAndHold(imgToDrag);
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        movetoElement = actions.moveToElement(dropHere);
        movetoElement.perform();
        movetoElement.release();
        Thread.sleep(6000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception occured in DragAndDropClass :: dragAndDropElement()", e);
    }
}
```

After running this code, nothing is happening I mean neither it is throwing any exception nor it is performing drag and drop functionality. What mistake I am doing here, can anybody help me to get out of this problem.

Comment: Check in other browsers also and do you see anything in browser console for errors or anything as such?

Comment: @TarunLalwani no it is not throwing any exception/error on browser console also, is there any mistake in my code?

Comment: These are hard ones to debug. Good luck

Comment: Is the site publicly accessible then please let me know. I will check at my end. Thanks.

Comment: @Subh no working on local environment, unable to make it public.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I have tried on chrome and firefox also, but even not working

Comment: @TusharDigambarDeshpande, if your page uses HTML5, then you might [not be able to perform drag and drop with the usual code.](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3604) You would probably need a jquery file as per the thread and use the same to perform the functionality as I am afraid there is no concrete solution with Selenium for HTML5 drag and drop, yet. 
Please confirm if it's a HTML5 one, in which case I will work and add the workaround solution for the same. Thanks. :)